# Why can't I parent two bones together?

Tags: rigging

I am trying to parent two bones together on the human body I made. For some reason, on 2.77, no matter what parent option I use, the bottom abdomen bone and the upper leg bone wont "connect" (as much as they can when it comes to parenting). I'm using this video to learn how to rig, but what it tells me to do doesn't match up with what is happening on my screen. Any suggestions, tips, or option changes I don't know about?   [Blender Rigging 1/2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9f-WVs3ghI)

Comment: Please show some screenshots of what you are trying to do. With respect, people aren't going to watch a 19 minute video to try and see where you went wrong.

Comment: It's around the time 4:30 to 5:00 in the video. Sorry, I didn't think about that XD

Answer (score 1):

The linked video shows parenting with an *Offset*. If you'd like the two bones to actually connect in your own rig, select *Connected* instead. Better yet, select the bone roots and hit <kbd>F</kbd> afterwards, so your original thigh bone stays nice and aligned with the rest of the leg.